# Getting all occurrences of a day in current month in Python

Tags: python, date

I'm Python noob and I need something that will boost my office work very much.

Getting to the point I need a function like that (pseudo code):

```
def return_dates(Monday):
   -do the job-
   return [2, 9, 16, 23, 30]
#(result bazing on DEC 2019)
```

So basically what I need is a function which will return a list of numbers which will represent occurences of a given day in current month.

I've tried to search through the stack but I couldn't find a solution in Python. I found date and calendar modules that could be useful in this case and I've tried to read the docs but I'm too noob to do it myself :(.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Occurences of what? Please provide more information of what you want to do, so its easier to help (or I just dont understand it :)

Comment: Occurences of a given date. For eg. I want all occurences of Mondays in current month (DEC 2019) so it will be 2, 9, 16, 23, 30, as I showed in example of a pseudo code. Thank you for getting interested in my problem.

Comment: Here is a tutorial, I hope this helps: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/date-time-exercise/python-date-time-exercise-24.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calendar` module ([`itermonthdays2`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdays2) method) to get the list of days:

```
import calendar

def get_days(year, month, day):
    """ day is: 0 - Monday
                ...
                6 - Sunday
    """
    c = calendar.Calendar()
    return [date for date, _day in c.itermonthdays2(year, month) if date != 0 and _day == day]


print(get_days(2019, 12, 0))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 9, 16, 23, 30]
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. That's exactly what I meant. Regards.